# Fatal error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on null in Quote.php

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, model, create-order

I am trying to create an order programatically. This is my code so far:

```
<?php

// Init magento base class
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Dummy data source
$settings   = array
(
    'WebsiteId' => 2,
    'StoreId' => 4,
    'ShippingMethod' => 'icw_shipping',
    'PaymentMethod' => 'icw_payment'
);
$jsonOrderData = '{"DiscountAmount":0, "DiscountReason":"", "STPointsUsed": 0, "STPointsEarned": 0,"CustomerId":17557,"SendConfirmation":true,"BasketData":[{"ProductId":18844,"Price":8.88,"Qty":1}],"ShippingMethod":"Flat Rate","DeliveryDate":"21/01/2016","SalesRep":"latheesan","PaymentMethod":"PayPal Here","PPHPaymentType":"CreditCard","PPHInvoiceId":"INV2-AHWG-SQHP-QMLT-1234","PPHTxId":"111-22-3333","ShippingAmount":15}';

//
// Test
//
echo '<pre>';
try
{
    // Init
    $orderCreator = new Ordercreator(
        $settings,
        $jsonOrderData
    );

    // Create order
    print_r($orderCreator->create());

    // Clean-up
    $orderCreator = null;
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo 'Failed to create order: '. $ex->getMessage() .' @ '. basename($ex->getFile()) .':'. $ex->getLine();
}
echo '</pre>';
//
// Test
//

/**
 * Helper class
 */
class Ordercreator
{
    // Class properties
    private $_settings        = array();
    private $_orderData       = array();
    private $_customer        = null;
    private $_quote           = null;
    private $_salesOrder      = null;

    // Class constructor
    function __construct(array $settings, string $jsonOrderData)
    {
        // Remember settings
        $this->_settings = $settings;

        // Parse sales order data
        $this->parseSalesOrderData($jsonOrderData);

        // Load order sales order customer
        $this->loadSalesOrderCustomer();

        // Initialise a new sales order quote
        $this->initSalesOrderQuote();
    }

    // Main method to initialise the order creation process
    function create()
    {
        // Add order lines to sales order quote
        $this->addOrderLinesToQuote();

        // Set shipping & payment method on quote
        $this->_quote
            ->getShippingAddress()
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod($this->_settings['ShippingMethod'])
            ->setPaymentMethod($this->_settings['PaymentMethod']);

        // Import additional payment data
        $this->_quote
            ->getPayment()
            ->importData(array(
                'method'          => $this->_settings['PaymentMethod'],
                'additional_data' => $this->_orderData->PaymentMethod 
            ));

        // Save quote and convert it to a real sales order
        $this->_quote
            ->collectTotals()
            ->save();
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();
        $this->_salesOrder = $service->getOrder();

        // Update custom sales order attributes
        $this->updateSalesOrderAttributes();

        // Parse result data
        $resultData = $this->_salesOrder->getData();

        // Clean-up
        $service                = null;
        $this->_settings        = null;
        $this->_orderData       = null;
        $this->_customer        = null;
        $this->_quote           = null;
        $this->_salesOrder      = null;

        // Success
        return $resultData;
    }

    // Method to parse sales order data
    protected function parseSalesOrderData($jsonOrderData)
    {
        $this->_orderData = @json_decode($jsonOrderData);
        if (!$this->_orderData)
            throw new Exception('Invalid order data');
    }

    // Method to load order customer
    protected function loadSalesOrderCustomer()
    {
        $this->_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $this->_customer->setWebsiteId($this->_settings['WebsiteId']);
        $this->_customer->load($this->_orderData->CustomerId);
        if (!$this->_customer->getId())
            throw new Exception('Invalid customer id '. $this->_orderData->CustomerId);
    }

    // Method to initialise a new sales order quote
    protected function initSalesOrderQuote()
    {
        // Create a new quote
        $this->_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $this->_quote->setStoreId($this->_settings['StoreId']);
        $this->_quote->setWebsiteId($this->_settings['WebsiteId']);

        // Validate customer's default address data
        if (!$this->_customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress())
            throw new Exception('Customer does not have a default billing address');
        if (!$this->_customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress())
            throw new Exception('Customer does not have a default shipping address');

        // Assign customer to the new quote
        $this->_quote->assignCustomer($this->_customer);

        // Set quote's billing & shipping address
        $this->_quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(
            $this->_customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()
        );
        $this->_quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(
            $this->_customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress()
        );
    }

    // Method to add order lines to sales order quote
    protected function addOrderLinesToQuote()
    {
        // Validate basket data
        if (!sizeof($this->_orderData->BasketData))
            throw new Exception('Basket data is empty');

        // Add basket data to sales order quote
        foreach ($this->_orderData->BasketData as $orderLine)
        {
            // Load product
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product->load($orderLine->ProductId);
            if (!$product || !$product->getId())
                throw new Exception('Product with id #'. $orderLine->ProductId .' does not exists');

            // Add product to sales order quote
            $this->_quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array(
                'price' => $orderLine->Price,
                'qty' => $orderLine->Qty
            )));
        }
    }

    // Method to update sales order attributes
    protected function updateSalesOrderAttributes()
    {
        $this->_salesOrder
            ->setSalesRep($this->_orderData->SalesRep)
            ->setDeliveryDate($this->_orderData->DeliveryDate)
            ->setPphPaymentType($this->_orderData->PPHPaymentType)
            ->setPphInvoiceId($this->_orderData->PPHInvoiceId)
            ->setPphTxId($this->_orderData->PPHTxId)
            ->save();
    }
}
```

When I execute the above, I get the following error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function isVirtual() on null in /home/www-data/test.domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php on line 292

Any ideas what this is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
```

with

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->_quote);
```

in the `Ordercreator::create` method.
the problem is that `$quote` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I am getting another error `Failed to create order: Please specify a shipping method. @ Mage.php:594` but I am setting the shipping method. Should I post this as a new question?

Comment: Yes please. New question.

Comment: ok done - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101322/programmatically-create-sales-order-using-quote-with-custom-shipping-method-pri